# fread и наследование

Tags: c++, наследование

Есть базовый класс media и 3 класса которые наследуются от него : USB, DVD, HDD. Все данные об этих устройствах хранятся в односвязном списке. И есть класс priceList(интерфейс программы) который объединяет все это. Как сохранять все эти данные в файл я вроде понял и сделал, с загрузкой из файла есть проблемы.

```
    void media::Load()// базовый
    {
        system("cls");
        char filename[MAX_PATH] = "Contacts.bin";
        FILE *f1 = nullptr;
        fopen_s(&f1, filename, "rb");
        if (f1 == NULL)
        {
            perror("Error: ");
            _getch();
            return;
        }
        LoadDataFromFile(f1);
        fclose(f1);
    }

    void media::LoadDataFromFile(FILE* f1)
    {
        fread(&name, 1, 20, f1);
        fread(&manufacturer, 1, 20, f1);
        fread(&model, 1, 20, f1);
        fread(&capacity, sizeof(int), 1, f1);
        fread(&quantity, sizeof(int), 1, f1);
    }

    void DVD::LoadDataFromFile(FILE* f1)
    {
        media::LoadDataFromFile(f1);
        int a;
        fread(&a, sizeof(int), 1, f1);
        setSpeedDVD(a);
    }

    void HDD::LoadDataFromFile(FILE * f1)
    {
        media::LoadDataFromFile(f1);
        int a;
        fread(&a, sizeof(int), 1, f1);
        setSpeedHDD(a);
    }

    void USB::LoadDataFromFile(FILE * f1)
    {
        media::LoadDataFromFile(f1);
        int a;
        fread(&a, sizeof(int), 1, f1);
        setSpeedUSB(a);
    }

    class priceList
    {
        List<media*> b;
        int count;
    }

template<typename T>
struct Element
{
    T data;
    Element * Next;
};

template<typename T>
class List
{
    Element<T> * Head;
    int Count;
}
```

Comment: @VladD, helpppp

Comment: Окей, а какие именно проблемы?

Comment: @VladD, сначала в файл я записываю вид устройства, допустим это будет USB. Считываю это из файла и вызываю USB::Load(), который тоже должен сделать fopen того же файла, чтобы считать остальную информацию, но так как файл уже открыт я больше это не могу сделать. То есть основная проблема что я не понимаю как считывать информацию и вызывать нужные мне методы загрузки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы по сути проводите сериализацию списка.

Если продолжать в таком же духе, как вы начали, то операцию открытия файла и проверок следует выгрузить из десериализатора отдельного объекта в десериализатор всего списка.

Таким образом, ваш код будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
void LoadMediaList()
{
    system("cls");
    char filename[MAX_PATH] = "Contacts.bin";
    FILE *f1 = nullptr;
    fopen_s(&f1, filename, "rb");
    if (f1 == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error: ");
        _getch();
        return;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        // пытаемся считать следующий элемент
        const size_t namelen = 3;
        char namebuf[namelen + 1];
        size_t nread = fread(buffer, sizeof char, namelen, f1);
        if (nread == 0) // больше ничего нет в файле -
            break;      // на выход
        if (nread != namelen)
        {
            // ошибка, данных меньше чем ожидалось
            // реагируйте подходящим образом
        }
        namebuf[namelen] = 0;
        // создадим объект нужного типа, согласно имени
        media* pMedia = AllocateMediaFor(namebuf);
        // пусть он сам десериализирует себя
        pMedia->LoadDataFromFile(f1);

        // а вот тут вставьте десериализированный объект в конец списка
        // !
    }
    fclose(f1);
}

media* AllocateMediaFor(char* name)
{
    if (strcmp(name, "USB") == 0)
        return new USB();
    if (strcmp(name, "DVD") == 0)
        return new DVD();
    if (strcmp(name, "HDD") == 0)
        return new HDD();
    // если мы здесь, надо сообщить об ошибке
    // продумайте стратегию обработки ошибок
}
```

---

Какие проблемы видно по вашему коду?

1. Вы пользуетесь структурами данных, подходящими для C, а не C++. Переходите от `char*`-строк к `std::string`, от `FILE*` к `istream` и т. д.
2. Вы пользуетесь самописными структурами данных (`class List`). НЕ изобретайте велосипед, возьмите готовые STL-контейнеры (`std::list` или `std::vector`).
3. Ваш код вовсе не контролирует ошибки. Продумайте, что делать в случае, если прочитались не все данные? Ваш код в его нынешнем состоянии этого просто не заметит. Игнорировать возвращаемое значение `fread` неправильно.
4. Вы пишете сериализацию вручную, это опять велосипед. Лучше всего воспользоваться сериализацией, поставляемой с boost: [boost.serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html). Потратьте своё время на логику программы, а не на технические проблемы, давно решённые другими!

Comment: @VlaaD, Спасибо, Ваши советы всегда очень помогают! У меня еще пара вопросов:
1. LoadMediaList() делать методом класса priceList?
2. Что означает эта фраза: "выгрузить из десериализатора отдельного объекта в десериализатор всего списка"?

Comment: @VlaaD, 3. Почему вы используете size_t, а допустим не int ?

Comment: @Lightness: 1. Да. 2. Метод `media::Load` не нужен, т. к. вы не будете открывать файл из-за одного элемента. Его код почти без изменений уходит в `priceList::LoadMediaList`. 3. Потому что `int` может быть отрицательным, а `size_t` — нет. Ну и `fread` тоже возвращает `size_t`. В общем, если нужна переменная под размер/количество значений/и т. п., часто лучше использовать `size_t`.